# A three-step puzzle

Tags: riddle, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

To figure out who I am, start by holding hands with my twin, then go up one floor and come back down. Then you'll have to take a deep  breath and drop down three stories - you'll be fine if you don't hit your head on the beams! And finally, run back up one and come down two floors, and then go halfway down.

After you've done all that, you'll recognize me right away.

Who am I?

*Hint (6 hours elapsed):*

> Drawing a picture of the path on paper, horizontally, may help.

*Bigger hint:*

> What artistic medium could "steps" and "beams" be hinting at?

Comment: I have tried drawing it on paper

Comment: Would a second hint be helpful?

Comment: Yes please can you?

Comment: Hopefully it is a bit clearer now :)

Comment: Well by artistic medium do you mean materials

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are:

> Chopin's Waltz #10 in B minor

Explanation:

> The steps and beams refer to the musical stanza, the "path horizontally on paper".  The traditional stanza has two identical parts, or "twins".  Also the "three-step" refers to the music being in 3/4 time.

To figure out who I am, start by holding hands with my twin,

> Start at E, but it's a tied note, ergo "holding hands"

then go up one floor and come back down.

> E-F-E

Then you'll have to take a deep breath and drop down three stories - you'll be fine if you don't hit your head on the beams!

> E-F-E-B, B passing into the space between the two "beams"

And finally, run back up one and come down two floors, and then go halfway down.

> E-F-E-B-C-A-Ab  This is the start to Chopin's waltz #10 in B minor.  If you go to [this online piano](http://bestclassicaltunes.com/DictionaryPiano.aspx) you can type in the notes and hear it for yourself!

Comment: AH! finalizing...

Comment: Small quibble: It starts on F# not E. But otherwise you are fully correct. Marking as the answer. Well done!